# Back to search results link

Tags: php

On my product page I want to include a link for "back to search results". The search results page is generated with a query string, so I need to include those same query string variables in my link.

I have tried using HTTP_REFERER but this does include the query string variables.

Also I don't think using sessions would be ideal in this case.

EDIT: I just tested again with HTTP_REFERER and this in actual fact works - I must have been doing it incorrectly in the first instance, but it does indeed append the query string variables. So I'll probably stick with this.

I am aware that HTTP_REFERER cannot be relied upon, but would that really be an issue in the case of a "back to search results" link?

Comment: what if your product page is not lead by a search?

Comment: Then I suppose I don't display the back link?

Comment: you already answer yourself how to solve the problem if you are able to do differentiate

Answer (score 2):

If the results are already generated, and you really don't want to generate anything else:

```
<a href="#" onClick="history.go(-1)">Back to results</a>
```

Comment: I understand this answer is 6 years old, therefore my 2 cents to update it since its almost 2000 views:  `href="javascript:window.history.back();` will work on firefox too.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to track the search query terms *somehow.* If you don't want to use `$_session` use `$_get` or `$_post`.  Then apply the query to the link "Back to search results."

Why is `$_session` not ideal?

On the search results page:

```
session_start();

$_session['searchterms'] = $_GET['searchterms'];

//loop products:
//<a href="productpage.php">product 1</a>
//etc.
```

On the product page:

```
echo "<a href=\"search_results.php?searchterms=$_sesssion['searchterms']\">Back to search results</a>";
```

Comment: Thanks. I prefer not to include additional get variables in my URLs and sessions aren't multi-window/multi-tab safe. I will probably have to post a hidden form or something.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion - If it is appropriate for your application, you could try caching the results on the client (browser) side.
You can see the examples of this using javascript, [here](http://monsur.com/projects/jscache/) and [here](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Browser-Side_Cache).